# Integrating Delta Function (multiplied by f(t) )

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

So i know the basic form for integrating delta functions with the bounds of integration being 0 to infinity, but I've been given a problem with different bounds and i'm a little lost on how to approach the problem. Here it is:

$$ \int_{-1}^6 (5+e^{-2t})\, \delta(t-2) \ dt$$

$f(t)$ would be defined as $5+e^{-2t}\,$ and normally I think the answer would be $f(a)$ which is $f(2)$ in this case, but i think the bounds change that.

Comment: You have it right.  The bounds only change the answer if they do not include the measure point for the delta function.

Comment: Thankyou! And also to add to this, if a is outside of the bounds of integration then the answer would be 0

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: @Alex Are you happy with my answer or do you need a better explanation?

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{-1}^6 (5+e^{-2t})\, \delta(t-2) \ dt= 5+e^{-2(2)}=5+e^{-4}$$

as $2 \in (-1,6)$.